Check run variables on an if statement
I am trying to check the value of a variable that is set when running.

I guess that is getting empty value.
My try:
variables:
- name: MailPass
  ${{ if eq( variables['SendMail'], 'Yes' ) }}:
    value: "Si"
  ${{ else }}:
    value: "No"

SendMail is a variable set when running (within the run dialog in the azure devops web) and MailPass is always getting "No" value, no matter what value I set to SendMail variable.
What is the correct syntax to make this comparison? (I've also tried variables.SendMail syntax, but same result)

Given that you're using a YAML pipeline, I'd recommend using parameters in pipelines instead of variables, as recommended by Kevin. But honestly I'd use a boolean parameter which will be displayed as a checkbox when queuing a new build, as opposed to a string parameter.

you are right. I used string because UI variables has no type, but using parameters it has fully of sense.

Exactly, parameters are strongly-typed so that alone is a good reason for using them.

I am afraid that we are not able to use if expression to check the variable set in the Pipeline UI.
When you set the variable in Pipeline UI, it will expand at runtime. But the if expression will be judged at compile time.
In this case, the variable will pass empty value to the If expression.
For a workaround, we can use the script to use logging command to set the variable based on the variable value.
Here is an example:
steps:

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      if(  "$(SendMail)" -eq "yes" )
      {
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MailPass;]Si"
      }
      else
      {
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MailPass;]No"
      }
- powershell: echo $(MailPass)

Result:


Or you can consider changing to use parameters to set the SendMail value. The parameters value can be used in If expression. Refer to this doc: Runtime Parameters
Here is an example:
parameters:
- name: SendMail
  type: string
  default: yes

variables:
- name: MailPass
  ${{ if eq( parameters.SendMail, 'Yes' ) }}:
    value: "Si"
  ${{ else }}:
    value: "No"

In this case, you can also set the parameters value at runtime.
For example:


Using parameters instead of variables solved my problems. Wonderful workaround ;)
